# Delete Duplicates in Multi-Dimension Array

Tags: ruby

```
A=[[a,3],[a,2],[a,1],[b,1],[b,3]]
```

I want to `uniq` the array by first element, but keep the item that has the largest second element

result should be

```
[[a,3],[b,3]]
```

Here is my code:

```
A.uniq{|i| i.first} 
=> [[a,1],[b,1]]
```

Comment: A.uniq{|i| i.first}   #=>  [[a,1],[b,1]]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And add your code by editing your questions because code is difficult to read in comments.

Comment: `a` and `b` are not Ruby objects (unless they are local variables or methods that you have not defined). I suggest you edit to make them strings or symbols. (I assumed they are strings in my answer.) It would be more accurate to say that you want to "group" (rather than `uniq`) the elements of `A` by their first elements, then select the element in each group whose last element is greatest. You can then simply translate that statement to Ruby code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

```
A=[['a',3],['a',2],['a',1],['b',1],['b',3]]

A.group_by(&:first).map { |_,v| v.max_by(&:last) }
  #=> [["a", 3], ["b", 3]]
```

The two steps:

```
h = A.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"a"=>[["a", 3], ["a", 2], ["a", 1]], "b"=>[["b", 1], ["b", 3]]} 
h.map { |_,v| v.max_by(&:last) }
  #=> [["a", 3], ["b", 3]]
```

Comment: Thank this is exactly what I want, Thank you Cary